# TRIGGER para impedir borrar registro con un identificador concreto

Tags: oracle, base-de-datos, plsql, trigger, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy haciendo un trabajo con PL/SQL,oracle y sqldeveloper y tengo una tabla a la cual le quiero crear un trigger que me impida borrar un registro que tenga en el campo id un 1. No sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Javi. Por favor edita tu pregunta con la opción **editar** en el pie para que agregues más información sobre tu problema: definición de la tabla, qué has intentado para crear el trigger, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con un trigger `BEFORE DELETE` de la siguiente forma

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BEFORE_DEL_TRIG
   BEFORE DELETE ON tabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   If :Old.id = 1 then
   Raise_Application_Error(-20099, 'Cannot delete this record.');
End If;
END;
/
```

El trigger revisa el valor de la columna que tu especifiques y lanza un error en caso de que la condición se cumpla.

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue perfecto!!

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue útil, puedes marcar la como correcta.